# Pulling links from list in php

Tags: php, html, string

```
<li class="page_item page-item-6"><a href="http://localhost/wordpress1006/?page_id=6">About us</a></li> 
<li class="page_item page-item-12"><a href="http://localhost/wordpress1006/?page_id=12">Contact</a></li> 
<li class="page_item page-item-10"><a href="http://localhost/wordpress1006/?page_id=10">Portfolio</a></li> 
<li class="page_item page-item-8"><a href="http://localhost/wordpress1006/?page_id=8">Services</a></li>
```

I need to pull links only from this list, I would use regular expressions but I'm too scared to try.
So numbers will change at the end of page_item page-item-number

what would you suggest me to do here?

Thanks in advance

Comment: btw I need to pull http: //part , without <a></a>

Comment: because I'm not good enough with regex @Kishore ;)

Comment: @OP: That's not a good reason to be afraid. Regexes are incredibly useful; it's worthwhile to learn them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
$matches = array();
$string = '
    <li class="page_item page-item-6"><a href="http://localhost/wordpress1006/?page_id=6">About us</a></li> 
    <li class="page_item page-item-12"><a href="http://localhost/wordpress1006/?page_id=12">Contact</a></li> 
    <li class="page_item page-item-10"><a href="http://localhost/wordpress1006/?page_id=10">Portfolio</a></li> 
    <li class="page_item page-item-8"><a href="http://localhost/wordpress1006/?page_id=8">Services</a></li> 
';
preg_match_all('/href="(.*?)"/i', $string, $matches);
var_dump($matches[1]);
```

Output:

```
array
  0 => string 'http://localhost/wordpress1006/?page_id=6' (length=41)
  1 => string 'http://localhost/wordpress1006/?page_id=12' (length=42)
  2 => string 'http://localhost/wordpress1006/?page_id=10' (length=42)
  3 => string 'http://localhost/wordpress1006/?page_id=8' (length=41)
```

(note it will fail on more complex HTML, in which case I would no longer use Regex, rather some thing like [Simple HTML DOM](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net))

Answer (score 2):

I thought this would be fun to answer. So, here is a solution of how to fetch the URL from HTML without regular expression.

```
$html = '
    <li class="page_item page-item-6"><a href="http://localhost/wordpress1006/?page_id=6">About us</a></li> 
    <li class="page_item page-item-12"><a href="http://localhost/wordpress1006/?page_id=12">Contact</a></li> 
    <li class="page_item page-item-10"><a href="http://localhost/wordpress1006/?page_id=10">Portfolio</a></li> 
    <li class="page_item page-item-8"><a href="http://localhost/wordpress1006/?page_id=8">Services</a></li>
';
$tidy = new tidy();
$tidy->parseString($html);
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($tidy->html());
$links  = $dom->getElementsByTagName('a');

$matches = array();
foreach ($links as $link) {
    $matches[] = $link->attributes->getNamedItem('href')->value;
}

var_dump($matches);
array(4) {
  [0]=>
  string(41) "http://localhost/wordpress1006/?page_id=6"
  [1]=>
  string(42) "http://localhost/wordpress1006/?page_id=12"
  [2]=>
  string(42) "http://localhost/wordpress1006/?page_id=10"
  [3]=>
  string(41) "http://localhost/wordpress1006/?page_id=8"
}
```

Comment: Simple HTML DOM is much easier: `foreach (str_get_html($html)->find('a') as $node) var_dump($node->href);`

Comment: @Petah Thanks for the information! You are probably right. I just like using native PHP when possible.

Comment: @Petah: Are you referring to this? http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/ Because `str_get_html` is not in the PHP docs.

Comment: @Mark yes I am referring to the **Simple HTML DOM** library

Comment: @Petah: Yes, I gathered that, but seeing as it's non-standard...there could be multiple projects with that name, or the project may have moved, or whatever.